# Shortest arbitrary path of length K

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I can't seem to figure out what problem class does this question belongs to:

Given a weighed bi-directional graph G, find the shortest path, where the length of the path is the sum of the weights, and the number of nodes in the path is  K, and that all nodes on the path are distinct.

The path can start and end at any point as long as it visits each node no more then once.

I had to solve it with brute force with k=3, but I'm wondering what would be a better solution for bigger k, since brute force would not be feasible.

Comment: "find shortest path of length K"... `return K`? :P You'll have to clarify how the weights are used

Comment: clarified, by shortest I meant that the length is not the number of edges but the sum of the weight. it's the terminology from weighed graphs, we never actually mean node length if there are weights https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: If you have k=V(G) you have a traveling salesman problem in hand, so unless you have some meaningful restriction on k this is going to be at least as hard as TSP in the general case.

Comment: true, but I'm interested in implementing this, so worst case complexity doesn't really help. for a specific k, for now I have solved with k=3 using brute force, can TSP help with k=3?

Comment: Isn't this something like calculating Hamiltonian path as Hamiltonian path is the one where you need to calculate the distance traveled from one point to another point covering all the points only once